# How to use NSURLRequest / NSURLConnection to download an mp3 file to app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

**The Situation**
In my app, I am currently downloading an mp3 file (to docs directory) using `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL]`, a method that works fine, but ties down the CPU, dissallowing screen updates of download status. So, I want to download using a different method so that I can update the screen *WHILE* downloading to alert the user that the download has begun.

**Question**
How do I set up my viewController to use **NSURLRequest** *or* **NSURLConnection** to download an mp3 file? (please give source)

Comment: You could just execute `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL]` on the background thread to avoid UI issues... in fact you should do this with any intensive processes that don't involve the UI.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use "NSURLConnection asynchronously" search for the term and you'll find source. Or just NSURLConnection.

For example:

[NSURLConnection NSURLRequest proxy for asynchronous web service calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959243/nsurlconnection-nsurlrequest-proxy-for-asynchronous-web-service-calls)