# Is it possible to download a .zip file into iPhone when user clicks a link inside UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

In a new app, I plan to let users download their own files and stored them inside iPhone. The process is typically:

- iPhone present a web page by UIWebView, in which there are several links to .zip files
- the user browser the page and click on one of the .zip file link
- iPhone downloads the file into the iPhone document folder, closes WebView, acknowledges the user when download is complete

How can that be done? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use NSURLRequest / NSURLConnection to download an mp3 file to app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204010/how-to-use-nsurlrequest-nsurlconnection-to-download-an-mp3-file-to-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to handle the click of the link yourself by capturing the request on your `UIWebViewDelegate` implementation, and then downloading the file with NSURLRequest asynchronously.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204010/how-to-use-nsurlrequest-nsurlconnection-to-download-an-mp3-file-to-app) is essentially the same thing at that point.  If you want to unzip, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412982/iphone-unzip).