# Connecting to a RESTful webservice in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, web-services, http-post

I tried connecting to a web service and retrieve data from it, but I did not succeed in doing so. Here is what I have done.

This is the web service I'm trying to connect to http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/software/rest.do

Here is my example.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface example : NSObject {

    NSMutableData *receivedData;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *receivedData;

- (void) getDataFromServer;
@end
```

Here is my example.m file:

## import "example.h"

```
@implementation example

@synthesize receivedData;

-(void) getDataFromServer {
    //prepare request
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/rest/search/"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [theRequest setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    
    NSString *myXmlQuery = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><orgPdbQuery><version>head</version><queryType>org.pdb.query.simple.AdvancedKeywordQuery</queryType><description>Text Search for: chloro</description><keywords>chloro</keywords></orgPdbQuery>"];
    
    
    //set Headers
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"application/xml"];
    [theRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", [myXmlQuery length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    
    //create the Body
    NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
    
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<xml>"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[myXmlQuery dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"</xml>"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    
    
    //post
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:postBody];
    
    NSLog(@"%@", myXmlQuery);
    
    //get response
    NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse = [[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc] init];
    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];
    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response code- %ld",[urlResponse statusCode]);
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", result);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"in didReceiveResponse....setting receivedData to zero");
    //[receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"In didReceiveData...receiving data and appending to receivedData");
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Connection failed with error");
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"in connectionDidFinishLoading");
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %ld bytes of data", [receivedData length]);
}

@end
```

I'm getting a html page as a response to this. Moreover, connectionDidFinishLoading is not being invoked any time because I'm not getting the NSLog statements in my output. All I am getting is the html version of the url I'm trying to connect to.

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thank you.

PS: I'm trying to format this text properly but it is automatically getting formatted like this. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: It's minor, but the REST URL is `/pdb/rest/search`. You have an additional slash appended. Some web services are a little picky about such things.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to do two different things. Firstly, I suggest you look at the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html). You also do not need to create a `NSHTTPURLResponse*` as that gets taken care of for you.

Secondly, you are trying to use the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` protocol without conforming to it, or adding your class as a delegate. This differs greatly from doing `sendSynchronousRequest` which will block the main thread, and does not need the delegate set because that method will wait for a response and not allow any other code to execute (hence blocking the thread). There's a really nice [StackOverflow question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959243/nsurlconnection-nsurlrequest-proxy-for-asynchronous-web-service-calls) very similar to yours.

In a nutshell:

1. Conform to `<NSURLConnectionDelegate>` in your interface.
2. Create a property for a `NSURLConnection*`
3. Use `self.myConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];`
4. Now you can rely on the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` protocol methods being called (`connectionDidFinishLoading:`, `connection:didReceiveData:`, etc).
5. Once you hit `connectionDidFinishLoading:` you can start using the data you downloaded.